# Display images from S3 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a web application in which I want to display images from my s3 bucket.
What do I need to do to make this FOLDER in my s3 publicly accessible so that anyone can see these images?
I want to be able to do something like

```
<img src="some source" />
```

with the url coming from the images in my s3 bucket.
Do I need to make changes to the CORDS policy?  Change permissions on the folder? etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The objects you want to have accessible via the web simply need public READ permission.  No other permissions are required.

You don't need any CORS configuration for simply displaying images with an `<img>` tag.

Also, you are talking about folders... those aren't really a thing on S3.  The key name can have slashes in it, yes, and that delimiter can be used for indexing the bucket, but folders don't really exist.